# CSS textarea positionning

Tags: html, css

I'm beginner on CSS.

I want to place the textarea in the right and the map in the left. But The box is displayed on the map.

Here is my CSS

```css
#CoordData {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: .9em;
   // position: absolute;
      left: 10px;
      right: 10px;
}
 #wrapper { 
                    position: absolute; 
                    left: 400px; 
                   // right: 10px; 
                    top: 10px; 
                    bottom: 10px; 
                } 
.Button {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: .6em;
  //  position: absolute;
      left: 200px;
      // right: 10px;
}
```

Could anyone help me please ?

Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/agr3a07m/132/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/agr3a07m/132/show/) the full screen view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ca simple change your jsfiddle like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3evmq519/)

where just change the absolute positione of your `#wrapper` this way

```
 #wrapper { 
                position: absolute; 
                //left: 400px; 
                right: 20%; 
                top: 1px; 
                bottom: 10px; 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .pull-left and .pull-right classes of Twitter Bootstrap UI framework or the bootstrap framework divides the page into 12 grids so you can use 6 grids for map and 6 grids for the text.

for reference on grids: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_basic.asp

for reference on pull-left:
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=pull-left-class

Hope its helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your replay !